# Implement function into js string variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, raty

Here I have a code to show for on place a PHOTO,NAME,RATING in SIDE_bar

but I only get first object, so I dont know what is wrong with this code:

```
var rating="";
if (!!place.rating) ocene = raty({ score: place.rating, path: 'http://wbotelhos.com/raty/lib/img' }); 
  var photo ="<img src='http://carsedia.com/code/voyage/icons/7.png'></img>";
  if (!!place.photos) photo = '<img src='+place.photos[0].getUrl({ 'maxWidth': 50, 'maxHeight': 50 })+'></img>';
  var htmlside = "<div class='element'>"+photo+"<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[" + parseInt(gmarkers.length - 1) + "],\"click\");'>" + place.name + "</a></br>" + ocene + "</div>";


  $(htmlside).appendTo('#side_bar');
}
```

Without rating and RATY plugin all works perfect.

Comment: Can you create an example in JSFiddle, JSBin or some other interactive tool to make it clearer?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/EVEWOta/90/edit

Comment: so is there some possible solutions ???

Comment: click on first screen to submit and you will get a sidebar in left side on screen...

Comment: When I wrote clearer, this is what I meant. I did not expect this mass of code, where I did not manage to find what you posted. You need to reduce your code to a minimally reproducible case. I believe that then  you will get much better assistance.

Comment: In the JSBin, the output starts with `">`. Validate your HTML first.